# Cross validation returning score over 1.0 what should I do?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

First I want to say I searched a lot before posting but didn't find anything about geting score greater then 1.0 (100%).

So first I use GridSearchCV to pick my model, but I didn't use the gamma parameter because the GridSearch was getting stuck. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

svr = SVR()
param_grid = {'kernel':['linear','rbf','poly','sigmoid'], 'C':[1,5,10,15], 'degree':[3,6,9,12,15]}
gscv = GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid, cv = 6)
gscv.fit(features, ranks)
print(gscv.best_score_)
print(gscv.score(features, ranks)*-1)
```

and it returns:

> -1.02488175821
>
> 0.583772756529

Then I use a SVC with the best parameters returned from the GridSearch adding gamma and epsilon as paramters. I am cross validating the new model using KFold and printing scores according to different metrics as MSE,MAE,R^2 but they return very different results.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import median_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
svr = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C = 10, epsilon = 0.001, gamma = 0.1)
scores = []
r2 = []
mae = []
mse = []
evs = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(ranks):
    x_train, x_test = features.iloc[train_index], features.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = ranks[train_index], ranks[test_index]
    svr.fit(x_train, y_train)
    predictions = svr.predict(x_test)
    mse.append(mean_squared_error(y_test,predictions))
    r2.append(r2_score(y_test,predictions))
    mae.append(median_absolute_error(y_test,predictions))
    evs.append(explained_variance_score(y_test,predictions))
    scores.append(svr.score(x_test,y_test))
    
print ('Classifier .score : {}'.format(np.asarray(scores).mean()*-1))  
print ('MSE score : {}'.format(np.asarray(mse).mean()))  
print ('R^2 score: {}'.format(np.asarray(r2).mean()*-1))
print ('MAE score: {}'.format(np.asarray(mae).mean()))
print ('EVS score: {}'.format(np.asarray(evs).mean()*-1))
```

This prints out

> Classifier .score : 1.0535368037228126
>
> MSE score : 0.004624197990041222
>
> R^2 score: 1.0535368037228126
>
> MAE score: 0.033673630575293226
>
> EVS score: 1.0293436224922894

But if I change the gamma to 0.2 it prints this

> Classifier .score : 0.5945396153777264
>
> MSE score : 0.0035847763619656497
>
> R^2 score: 0.5945396153777264
>
> MAE score: 0.023670574621059648
>
> EVS score: 0.5778668299600922

1. So my question is what am I doing wrong?
2. What I am supposed to do in this case?
3. How is it possible to get a score higher than 1.0?
4. Why some of the scores are 0.02 (I couldn't find what is the highest
   for this scoring method, but in sklearn documentation I saw that
   there are 0.8 in the example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 : Indeed R2 shouldn't be >1 but you have a score higher than 1 because you multiply by (-1). 
And there is absolutely no reason R2 shouldn't be negative. 
You can check the doc for r2_score : 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html
It just means that your model didn't work so well...

4 : If I'm not wrong, MSE and MAE are indicators that you should use for regression. It's not natural to use them for classification. I think you should stick to R2
If you need more indicators you can try this :

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

Also, just a remark : svr.score will calculate R2  automatically so you don't need to use metrics.r2_score.

2 : Maybe you should try differents models like random forest, XGBoost, Extra trees, KNN...

Hope that helped you ! Good luck

Comment: Well SVR is a regression, so MSE and MAE then should be relevant but then what does their score mean ? and the - 1 is not the case with or without is it is the same but in one of the cases it is with -

Comment: My bad, I thought you were doing a classification.
MAE : Mean Absolute Error, MSE : Mean Squared Error. 
the more it's close to 0, the better but having 0.003 doesn't mean it's "good". This will depend on the scale of your target variable. You may need to normalize you target variable to have a score between 1 and 0

Comment: My target is actually between 0 and 0.4

Comment: then the last one you built with gamma = 0.2 does'nt seem that bad !

Just to precise : 

R2 = 1 - aPositiveQuantity so it's mathematically impossible for it to be >1. But indeed if you multiply your score (-1,05) by -1 it's gonna be > 1.

Also, you may want to re-do a param grid with only the gamma parameter.
 
last thing : If you do a regression, you shouldn't call an indicator "classifier score"